# How to use travel/ date

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm sorry if my question is too basic. I don't find many examples of "travel" in a time context, only place. Please tell me if the next sentences are correct, incorrect, and if there is a more natural way to say it

-I will travel on Dec1-Jan1

-I will travel from Dec1 to Jan1

-I will travel between Dec1 and Jan1

-I will be on travel on Dec-Jan1

-I will be on travel from Dec1 to Jan1

-I will be on travel between Dec1 and Jan1

-I will be traveling on Dec1-Jan1.... etc.

Answer (score 1):

"I will be traveling" is the most idiomatic, at least in American English. "I will travel" is less idiomatic, but grammatical. "I will be on travel" is not grammatical.

Comment: "I will be on travel" is at the same time incorrect and something I could imagine saying in a business context.

Comment: @Photon I shall restrain myself from commenting on business English.

Comment: You forgot to end your comment with "going forward".